# Why is this setter method in the Node class not working?

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list, properties, setter

I am trying to build kinda dynamic array. When trying to assign the array's last space the ignite property's set method creates a node and assigns this node's next reference. That's what I am thinking.

But this set method not even working and I am getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` error. What is the problem? Is it possible?

[CODE IN THE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAQ0r.jpg)

(My English is not good - sorry for this)

```
public class DynamicArray
{
    public static int index = 0;
    public Node head;
    public static Node last;
    
    public DynamicArray()
    {
        head = new Node();
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public object[] datas = new object[10];
        private object ignite = new object();
        public Node? next;

        public object Ignite 
        {   
            get 
            { 
                return ignite; 
            }
            set 
            {
                next = new Node();
                ignite = value;
            }
        }

        public Node()
        {
            datas[9] = Ignite;
            last = this;
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Add(object data)
    {
        last.datas[index] = data;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need two constructors.  One with a parameter value and one without.  The issue is "new Node()" which is inside the constructor Node(), the object Ignite.  Your code is in a recursive loop and getting an error.  Public Node() {} and Public Node(int value) {your code}

Comment: No,program is not in recursive loop because its not giving StackOverflowException. To trigger set method in Ignite it must be called directly like Ignite = data.

Comment: It will give an exception when you use the SET method.  When you do new Node() it call the Ignite() method which does a new Node() which calls the ignite.  It is an endless loop.